# How did Job and Noah know that they should make sacrifices to God?

Tags: old-testament, job

The sacrifice system was received after Exodus and is described in Leviticus. Also in Leviticus it is described what clean and unclean animals were.

1. How could Job and Noah know that they should be doing sacrifices and in Noah’s case what clean animals are(Genesis 8:20–21)?
2. How did Job know who the real(Jewish) God is, when he was not Jewish and God has not revealed his sacrificial commandments in Leviticus, yet?

It seems to me that this is good evidence that Jews invented these stories and put their current understandings in them, not realizing that the people in the stories would not have known about their current Jewish laws.

Argument from silence like "well, probably God did tell them somehow" is not a good argument.

Comment: A "formal" sacrifice system was delineated in Exodus and Leviticus. Recall that sacrifices are mentioned as earlier in Genesis with respect to Abel and Cain's sacrifices.

Comment: Did God said anything to Cain or Abel about that he wants a sacrifice? And moreover that the sacrifice is for forgiveness of sins?

Comment: The question shows lack of research, ignoring scripture and, thus, drawing false conclusions. Further clarity and detail is required.

Comment: You're assuming that they *should* have made sacrifices, but the Biblical texts don't say that, only that they *did*.

Comment: Some of the context in the answers to this question might be helpful: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14859/did-adam-and-eve-ever-practice-animal-sacrifice

Answer (score 4):

> Argument from silence like "well, probably God did tell them somehow" is not a good argument.

This is incredibly biased. Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence; indeed, that claim is a well-known fallacy, which you are deliberately invoking.

Fortunately, we have plenty of *positive* evidence as well. In fact, God is explicitly recorded as talking to Adam (Genesis 2-3), Eve (Genesis 3), Cain (Genesis 4), Noah (Genesis 7-9), Job (Job), and many others. The idea that the *only* information God communicated to men is exactly what is recorded is simply absurd, and we see Cain and Abel offering sacrifices, and Noah doesn't seem to need to be told about clean and unclean animals.

So... why is this information missing?

A better question to ask is why do we expect it to be present? When telling a story, you generally don't fill in background information your audience already knows. It seems quite clear that people before Moses knew God, and knew at least some of what he expected in terms of laws and/or religious practice.

Another consideration is that Moses is generally credited for writing Genesis. That isn't to say that Genesis is fiction; rather, Moses took prior sources and compiled them into what we have today. Given that this likely happened at about the same time Leviticus was written (or at least at a time when Moses knew that Leviticus *would be* written), it's entirely plausible that he would have considered rehashing laws, practices and customs predating Leviticus to be superfluous.

It's true that Scripture is intended for us, today, but it was *also* intended for its contemporary audience... and for pre-Incarnation Jews, explaining the need and reasons to offer sacrifices would be as gratuitous as explaining the need and reasons to consume food or beverage. Thus, to them it would not be surprising that sacrifices are mentioned only occasionally, just as eating and drinking are mentioned only occasionally. Nor would it be any more surprising for no reason to be stated than for every instance of eating or drinking to omit "because he was hungry" or "because she was thirsty"; that information would be self-evident to the reader... just as it should be self-evident to *us* because we have the context of all of Scripture from which to infer such things. (It should be noted that there are *many* places in which understanding Scripture requires background knowledge; Genesis is hardly unusual in this respect.)

At any rate, the idea that God had not yet revealed Himself is clearly nonsense. The argument that people prior to Moses could not have known information that is not *recorded* prior to Leviticus is simply, and overtly, fallacious. It makes no sense when Scripture is considered in its original context, and it makes no sense when considered in our context today. In both cases, the "missing" information is either well known, or trivially inferred, from other sources.

Comment: Where is the need for sacrifices for atonement for sins first mentioned? People would not have known to do them except that God said it explicitly to them. At which point did he say it explicitly and clearly?

Comment: How would you prove that God said it and it was clear for the persons mentioned, if he did not do it in the recorded story before the sacrificial events? Why assuming that he did is more reasonable than that he didn't, when it is clear that he didn't?

Comment: "...when it is clear that he didn't", no, that's only "clear" in your imagination. Just as it's "clear" that Adam and Eve never drank a thing in their entire lives, because it's not recorded that they did. Now, I can't *prove* that they specifically drank anything, but I can *infer* from the evidence that they lived for more than a week (hundreds of years, in fact). Just as I can *infer* that people knew to offer sacrifices as evidenced by them *doing so*.

Comment: Drinking is not as important topic as the sacrifice and forgiveness of sin is - which in fact is mentioned over and over in many places in OT.
So, I don't think that your example is with the same weight as my question and argument.

Then, if it is well known for the people and it worked as simple as it was described(just a simple sacrifice), why would we have so explicit descriptions in Leviticus of how the sacrifices should be done?

Comment: Not to mention that only Cain and Abel are recorded to do offering in the earliest account in Genesis, like Adam and Eve didn't have to(although they did the initial sin), so if anyone needed to do a sacrifice, that would be Adam and Eve.

Comment: @CuriousGuy, you seem to have missed Genesis 3:21. Again, however, your *entire case* is based on the assertion that you know better what details are "important", and you appear impervious to reasons why you might be wrong. Therefore, I see little value in continuing this conversation. (Which is too long as it is. Take it to chat.)

Answer (score 2):

> The sacrifice system was received after Exodus and is described in Leviticus.

It's true that it was recorded by Moses in Leviticus, but there is no reason to believe that sacrifices didn't exist before that time, nor even that there wasn't some form of priesthood.

Genesis records that sacrifices were being offered right from the beginning:

> Abel also brought of the firstborn of his flock and of their fat.
> And the LORD respected Abel and his offering,
> — Genesis 4:4 (NKJV throughout)

> Then Noah built an altar to the LORD, and took of every clean animal and of every clean bird, and offered burnt offerings on the altar.
> — Genesis 8:20

> Then Melchizedek king of Salem brought out bread and wine; he was the priest of God Most High.
> — Genesis 14:18

> Then Abraham lifted his eyes and looked, and there behind him was a ram caught in a thicket by its horns.
> So Abraham went and took the ram, and offered it up for a burnt offering instead of his son.
> — Genesis 22:3

> Then Jacob offered a sacrifice on the mountain, and called his brethren to eat bread.
> And they ate bread and stayed all night on the mountain.
> — Genesis 31:54

What Moses did was to *make a formal written record* of how the Levitical priesthood should administer sacrifices.

This may have included new procedures and ceremonies specific to the covenant with Israel, but it would also have included the knowledge of sacrifices to God that had previously been passed down as traditional practice.

The same applies to God's commandments:

> And I will make your [Isaac's] descendants multiply as the stars of heaven;
> I will give to your descendants all these lands; and in your seed all the nations of the earth shall be blessed;
> because *Abraham obeyed My voice and kept My charge, My commandments, My statutes, and My laws*.
> — Genesis 26,4–5

Comment: " but there is no reason to believe that sacrifices didn't exist before that time, nor even that there wasn't some form of priesthood."

Why is it more reasonable that they existed without previous God commandments about them?
If God have commanded them to the mentioned persons, how hard could it be to be mentioned and explained what and why he commanded?

Comment: @CuriousGuy. There are two obvious possibilities: 1) God told people about his laws, commandments, requirement for sacrifices, etc. but while this is implied, it wasn't explicitly recorded; or 2) Moses, or whoever wrote the Torah, made up a lot of stuff, like parting the Red Sea and getting tablets carved personally by God himself. ¶ Many people *do* believe the second alternative, but for them to discuss it on this site is a waste of everyone's time, just as it would be to talk about miracles on the Physics.SE or Chemistry.SE sites.

Comment: I see you are a college(programmer), but with a lot more experience than me.
What happens when a software design is implemented with a lot of fundamental assumptions without looking at the requirements?
I think it is very normal for intelligent beings like humans to interact clearly and unambiguously. But God is supposed to be much more intelligent than us, and moreover he would know how "stupid" we are and that we need more clear instructions.

So, I don't think that is a waste of time. I want to hear other people's opinion, so I can be honest and open for logical explanations.

Comment: All I want you to do is be honest and apply how real life works to the assumptions you make for that "God must have told them, but it was not important enough to be mentioned".

Please tell me, honestly, if you have been doing your job for so many years with the same attitude and logic, what would the results have been?

Comment: @CuriousGuy, it isn't "assumptions", it's conclusions from deductive and abductive reasoning. There's a choice between trusting the data and making use of it, and disbelieving the data and ignoring it. Many people believe the Bible is mostly fairy tales, and they don't trust the data. Other people make a single assumption, that the Bible *is* true. I can respect both positions, but I can't respect people that decide to pick and choose which of the supernatural parts of the Bible they want to believe in.

Comment: Are you referring to me in your last sentence?

Comment: @CuriousGuy, in fact, your argument shows exactly why we might *not* have "instructions"... ***they aren't relevant to us***. The instructions that *are* relevant, *are* recorded... in Leviticus (and later; eventually, in the NT). Again, your entire case is based on attacking God for leaving out gratuitous and readily-inferred minutia. You ask for "logical explanations", but your own position *isn't* logical, and when you are *offered* those explanations, you reject them out of hand.

Comment: @Matthew, I don't find my position illogical. I asked a very simple question, we as humans do this every day. We do this every day in all kinds of forms. For example, if your friend tells you something that you never thought of, you would ask him "Wait, where did you hear this?". The case is the same here - as you start reading Genesis no sacrifices are mentioned to be required and then they suddenly appear, again with no explanation, up until Leviticus. It's simple as that.
I don't reject your explanations, because I am biased. But seems you are rejecting mine, because you are?

Comment: @CuriousGuy asks "*Are you referring to me in your last sentence?*". Not intentionally. If you "pick and choose which of the supernatural parts of the Bible they want to believe in", then obviously yes. But I have no way of knowing your thoughts, so no.

Comment: @RayButterworth yes, I definitely don't like the "pick and choose", although I have been doing it for a long time, without realizing it. As I recently started rereading the Bible as is from scratch without presuppositions, I started wondering questions like this one :)

Comment: @CuriousGuy, statements like "this is good evidence that Jews invented these stories", or your apparent resistance to reasonable explanations, don't give the impression of being "without presuppositions". While your actual question may be valid, the way in which you approach it does not seem neutral. From a standpoint of neutrality, 'are such details necessary' would be an equally valid question... and we propose that the answer to *that* is 'no'.

Comment: @CuriousGuy, as to the question of whether Genesis is fabrication, consider this. There are hundreds of flood legends spanning nearly every culture, making it likely that there is some truth to them. Also, while it's often claimed that the Jews copied the Babylonian myth (which was *written down* earlier), the boat in that one (and many others) is patently absurd, whereas Noah's Ark is of a nearly-optimal design. Which is more likely; a bunch of ancient, dumb nobodies copied a fictional story *and made it much more plausible*, or the Noahic story was the original?

Answer (score 2):

It was God himself who instituted sacrifice :

> Unto Adam also and to his wife did the LORD God make coats of skins, and clothed them. [Genesis 3:21 KJV]

The source of the skins is not revealed. Therefore the implication is that a source is to be revealed in the future.

After this event, Abel follows the example :

> And Abel, he also brought of the firstlings of his flock and of the fat thereof. And the LORD had respect unto Abel and to his offering: [Genesis 4:4 KJV]

Following the divine example, Abel sacrificed of his flock and brought the fat. And God respected that Abel had taken note of His own action and had followed that example.

Noah follows the precedents set previously.

Job also follows these precedents.

These are obedient, faithful people who notice what God has done and who notice what their forebears have done and they humbly follow the way that has been shown them.

Comment: That is interesting idea. But there is 1 problem - if God didn't mention that the sacrifice that Cain and Abel did is needed for atonement for sins, then why would Noah and Job follow them? Are they just copying without understanding? Seems that only Job understands the purpose.

The text does not explain why Noah did the sacrifice - he just did it(with clean animals). How does he know what a clean animal is?

Job on the other hand is doing the sacrifices for the correct reason(which would be described much much later in the OT) - for forgiveness of sins.

Isn't this fishy?

Comment: @CuriousGuy  You are not following the text of the scripture. Adam confessed his sin. God promised a 'seed' would rise above the serpentine Spirit and would (from above) bruise his head. An ascension. God slaughtered and provided skins. The man and the woman were clothed in another kind of nature than that in which they had been created. All these things are pregnant with spiritual allusion and truth. (But only if one is penitent and believing ; and only if God reveals these things to one's longing soul : the rich, he sends empty, away.)